# Id of saved object not reflected in list

Tags: java

A list of cars is created which aren't stored in the database.
Via setSaveCars values are set and the cars are saved in the database.
After the saveAndFlush the id is set, the id under which it's saved in the database.
This is shown in the returned object but not in the list.
Below a simplified example code snippet plus the outcome when testing with a list of 2 cars.

The outcome of this code is with a list of 2 cars:
car id:18902
car id:18903
cars id: 0
cars id: 0

Can sombody explain this behaviour?

```
private List<Car> setSaveCars(List<Car> cars) {
   for (Car car : cars) {
        car.setBrand("BMW");            
        car = carRepository.saveAndFlush(car);
        System.err.println("car id:" + car.getId());
   }
      
   System.err.println("cars id:" + cars.get(0).getId());
   System.err.println("cars id:" + cars.get(1).getId());
   return cars;
}
```

Comment: The reason is that you reassign the `car` variable. That variable holds a copy of the reference to the list element. Reassigning that variable does not change the element in the list.

Comment: What you actually want here is: `return cars.stream().peek(car -> car.setBrand("BMW")).map(carRepository::saveAndFlush).collect(toList())`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you reassign the `car` variable. That variable holds a copy of the reference to the list element. Reassigning that variable does not change the element in the list.

You can either extract just the value you want:

```
for (Car car : cars) {
    car.setBrand("BMW");            
    car.setId(carRepository.saveAndFlush(car).getId());
    System.err.println("car id:" + car.getId());
}
```

Or correctly work on the list by re-setting each entry. This requires the implementation of your `List<Car> cars` to be mutable, which it might not be.

```
for (int i=0;i<cars.size(); i++) {
    Car car = cars.get(i);
    car.setBrand("BMW");            
    car = carRepository.saveAndFlush(car);
    cars.set(i, car);
    System.err.println("car id:" + car.getId());
}
```

You should also take not of the approach that Seelenvirtuose posted in the comments. It creates a whole new `List` which might not be what you want, but it sure is elegant.

Comment: Thanks for the help it makes it clear for me